# Сложности с обновлением данных модели User через форму

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model, django-template

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я хочу обновлять фото профиля пользователя через форму на сайте. Мой код не выводит ошибок и аватарки при отправки формы сохраняются по пути /media/avatars/ удачно. Но при этом при обновления страницы профиля или переходе в профиль пользователя в admin панели, аватарка не меняется и сохраняется предыдущей. Само изменение аватарки через admin панель также работает хорошо. Был бы очень благодарен за любую подсказку. Ранее были проблемы с уточнением присваивания аватарки конкретному пользователю, но эта строчка кода: instance=request.user мне помогла. Не могут ли быть проблемы например в ней?

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Kind(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="avatars/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1, verbose_name='Пол')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Kind.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Forms.py:

```
from .models import Kind
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BookForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Kind
        fields = ['avatar']
```

Views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from Вход.forms import *
from .models import *

def profilee(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/accounts/login")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = BookForm()

        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form' : form})

def LogoutView(request):
    return redirect("/accounts/login")
```

Template:

```
<div>
 {% if not user.profile.avatar %}
 {% if user.profile.kind == "М" %}
 <div class="block">
 <img src="{% static 'image/m.png' %}" class="img-lg rounded-circle mb-4 imagero round" alt="image">
 </div>
 {% endif %}

 {% if user.profile.kind == "Ж" %}
 <div class="block">
 <img src="{% static 'image/j.png' %}" class="img-lg rounded-circle mb-4 imagero round" alt="image">
 </div>
 {% endif %}
 {% endif %}

 {% if user.profile.avatar %}
 <img src="{{ user.profile.avatar.url }}" class="img-lg rounded-circle mb-4 imagero round" alt="image">
{% endif %}


<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<h4>{% if user.first_name %}{{ user.first_name }}{% endif %} {% if user.last_name %}{{ 
 user.last_name }}{% endif %}</h4>
 <p class="text-muted mb-0">Social Activist</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**При запросе `POST`, после `if form.is_valid():`**

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.user = request.user
obj.save()
```

Так-же вам стоит убрать `instance=request.user` т.к. форма ожидает в качестве `instance` получить объект типа `Kind`, а вы передаете `User`

**При запросе `GET`:**

- Чтобы заполнить форму объектом `Kind` текущего юзера: `form = BookForm(instance=request.user.kind)`

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и решение проблемы!

Comment: Только к сожалению form = BookForm(instance=request.user.kind) для меня не работает. Пишет, что нет такого атрибута.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил что вы в вашей модели указали related_name='profile'. В таком случае правильным вариантом будет form = BookForm(instance=request.user.profile)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень мне помогли! Несмотря на мой слабый уровень!

Comment: В будущем, кто будет делать что-то похожее не забывайте написать instance=. Это было частью моей проблемы :)

Comment: Всегда рад помочь)